# Make a function which draw a plot and save it

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following dataset.

```
structure(list(Rf = c(60.105, 62.205, 64.305, 64.305, 66.405, 
66.405), Es = c(0, -0.07, -0.36, -0.47, -0.39, -1.54), H = c(32.3, 
-6.9, -5.59, -14.4, -6.5, -21), S = c(267, 136, 151, 114, 143, 
90.4), G = c(-46.8, -47.3, -50.7, -48.5, -49, -47.8)), .Names = c("Rf", 
"Es", "H", "S", "G"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Me", 
"Et", "Pr", "iPr", "Bu", "tBu"))
```

I need to plot Rf vs H, S and G, and the same for Es column. There is six plots in total.

To draw single plot I use the following function:

```
ggplot(data=df, aes(x=Rf, y=H, label=row.names(df))) + 
  geom_point(size=4) +
  geom_text(vjust=2) + 
  ylab(expression(list(Delta*H^o,~kJ/mol))) + 
  xlab("Molecular refraction") + 
  ylim((min(df$H) - 0.2*(abs(min(df$H)))), max(df$H)) + 
  opts(axis.line = theme_segment(size=1),
       axis.text.x = theme_text(colour="black", size=15),
       axis.text.y = theme_text(colour="black", size=15),
       axis.title.x = theme_text(colour="black", size=15),
       axis.title.y = theme_text(colour="black", size=15, angle=90),
       panel.background=theme_rect(colour="white"),
       panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(), 
       panel.grid.major = theme_blank())
```

[image]

I want to create a function like

```
f1 <- function(x.label, y.label, df, xtitle, filename) {
  g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=x.label, y=y.label, label=row.names(df))) + 
    geom_point(size=4) +
    geom_text(vjust=2) + 
    ylab(expression(list(Delta*y.label^o,~kJ/mol))) + 
    xlab(xtitle) + 
    ylim((min(df[,y.label]) - 0.2*(abs(min(df[,y.label])))), max(df[,y.label])) + 
    opts(axis.line = theme_segment(size=1),
         axis.text.x = theme_text(colour="black", size=15),
         axis.text.y = theme_text(colour="black", size=15),
         axis.title.x = theme_text(colour="black", size=15),
         axis.title.y = theme_text(colour="black", size=15, angle=90),
         panel.background=theme_rect(colour="white"),
         panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(), 
         panel.grid.major = theme_blank())
  ggsave(filename, g)
}
```

To call it for the example above like

```
f1(Rf, H, df, "Molecular refraction", "D:/temp/1.jpg")
```

The difficulty is how to transfer and correctly handle `x.label` and `y.label`, since they are used in `aes` option of `ggplot`, `ylab(expression())` and `ylim` calls. Curent function return an error `Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x.label' not found`

**ANSWER:**

The following function works correctly. `aes_string` should be used insted of `aes` in `ggplot` option, and `substitute` instead of `expression` in `ylab`.

```
f1 <- function(x.label, y.label, df, x.title, filename) {
  g <- ggplot(data=df, aes_string(x=x.label, y=y.label)) + 
    geom_point(size=4) +
    geom_text(aes(label=row.names(df)), vjust=2) + 
    ylab(substitute(list(Delta*y.label^o,~kJ/mol), list(y.label=y.label))) + 
    xlab(x.title) + 
    ylim((min(df[,y.label]) - 0.2*(abs(min(df[,y.label])))), max(df[,y.label])) + 
    opts(axis.line = theme_segment(size=1),
         axis.text.x = theme_text(colour="black", size=15),
         axis.text.y = theme_text(colour="black", size=15),
         axis.title.x = theme_text(colour="black", size=15),
         axis.title.y = theme_text(colour="black", size=15, angle=90),
         panel.background = theme_rect(colour="white"),
         panel.grid.minor = theme_blank(), 
         panel.grid.major = theme_blank())
  ggsave(filename=filename, plot=g)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you input `x.label` as a character (or string), i.e. `"Rf"`, you can use `aes_string` to map the aesthetics:

```
aes_string(x = x.label, etc)
```

Subsetting the `data.frame` then also becomes easy:

```
df[[x.label]]
```

For the expression for `ylab` you might need to use `parse` and/or `eval`, but I haven't got access to R right now and am unable to check.

Comment: `aes_string` should work but when I change `aes` to `aes_string` it seems `label` option doesn't work properly, because the function returns an error: `eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Me' not found`. Thanks for suggestion of using `eval` and `parse` functions, I'll try to use them.